# Negative Algebra Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Quite simple for you Math Genius but I'm struggling to understand the following equation. (I've only just started an introductory course in Mathematics and I'm keen to learn) :)

**I'm getting 2 answers**

On my scientific Calculator $= 5.4$

On this [website](https://www.cymath.com/answer?q=10%2B6*-8%2F2(-25)*-10%2B5) $= -5985$

My formula below. First I would like to know which one is correct or an explanation as to why they can both be correct. if someone could then break it down for me so I can understand where I have gone wrong.

$$10+6\cdot-\frac{8}{2(-25)}\cdot(-10)+5=$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest the mistake seems to lie somewhere within the interpretation of your given parenthesis hence it is not clear at all. The website you are refering to interprets your input as

$$10+6\cdot-\frac{8}{2}(-25)\cdot(-10)+5=-5985$$

where on the other hand you are asking for the evaluation of

$$10+6\cdot-\frac{8}{2(-25)}\cdot(-10)+5=5.4$$

The simple mistake is that the calculator you used online did not know that the $(-25)$ belongs to the denominator. Therefore [use more parenthesis](https://www.cymath.com/answer?q=10%2B6*-8%2F(2(-25))*-10%2B5) to make sure what you want to be computed.

Comment: To be honest I didn't know the (-25) belonged to the denominator. Stupid question again but should you not calculate 8/2= ans(-25)=

Comment: As I already mentioned it is a question of interpretation hence you seem to be unsure for yourself could you maybe add where this task came from? What exactly do you mean with $8/2=\operatorname{ans}(-25)$?

Comment: I understand what you mean in regards to interpretation.

Comment: I understand what you mean in regards to interpretation. But based on my initial calculation which was 10+6*-8/2(-25)*-10+5 until a moderator changed it to look like the above, is there any correct way of tackling the mathematical calculation(in its simple form) or is it based purely on interpretation? Because that would mean the calculation is formed wrong and is open for interpretation? is that correct? if i'm confusing you even more then don't worry about it, I will speak to my tutor about it.:)

Comment: I edited your question ^^' The problem about "10+6*-8/2(-25)*-10+5" is that it is not clear where the $(-25)$ belongs to. And so yes, it is only a question of interpretation. One could write "10+6*-8/(2(-25))*-10+5" to make clear it belongs within the denominator or leave it as it was and so it would be likely to be interpreted as $(-25)$ within the nominator. Both interpretations are possible and lead to your two provided solutions. I guess you have to ask your tutor to make things clear.

Comment: I think she might have done it on purpose to make me arrive at this conclusion. #lessonlearned

Comment: Well then I guess your question is answered and you can accept my answer so that other can see you are satisfied :)

Comment: The discrepancy comes about because of the temptation to interpret the expression in different ways. If you change the expression so as to remove the ambiguity, you eliminate the question. That's why I think the edit to the question was a mistake. I would suggest the following instead: `$$10+6\cdot-8/2(-25)\cdot-10+5=$$`. This is more readable than the original format, but preserves the ambiguity of the expression.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, I realised this for myself and I will keep it in my mind for further questions of this kind.